# Hiding text in emacs

Tags: emacs

Every time I open up emacs, I tend to get this text on my screen.. How do I permanently hide it? Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbSPt.jpg

Comment: Does this help? [How do I change the scratch message in Emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498258/how-do-i-change-the-scratch-message-in-emacs)

Comment: yeah! I am a little new to emacs.. How do I actually execute this command? is it "m-!" but where do I add "(setq inhibit-startup-message t)" to to disable that scratch message? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to this related StackOverflow answer [How do I change the scratch message in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1502022/4440445), you can suppress the message by setting

```
(setq initial-scratch-message nil)
```

in your configuration. If you don't already have a personal configuration file (usually `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` you can create one, using `emacs` or otherwise, and simply paste the command in verbatim, then save and exit. Next time you start `emacs`, the scratch buffer should be empty.

Comment: I am running both those commands and they are not working ***~/.emacs.d/init.el*** and I get nothing exists. When I run **~/.emacs ** I get permission denied, then I run my terminal as root and it says directory doesn't exist. Does this have to be created and if so, how do I do this and where do I have to save it to? Also, when I open up emacs, what is the key combination to start typing in the verbatim, or the very bottom of the screen? I can't seem to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: @Kdrumz you don't *run* them, you *edit* them e.g. open them in emacs or `nano ~/.emacs.d/init.el` and type/paste the command in

Comment: okay, i just did that. When I open emacs, the buffer is still there.. What did I do wrong?    http://imgur.com/a/XZmS3

Comment: This is also showing up when I open up a blank .cpp file http://imgur.com/a/UxMFw   I have never had these problems when using emacs, should I just uninstall it and try again?